# Resource Injection Type Mismatch

Tags: java, resources, code-injection

The following code returns Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Class

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Queue;


public class JmsMessageCollector {

    @Resource(name="My_connFactory",type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory") 
    private static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Resource(name="WIAM_connFactory", type=javax.jms.ConnectionFactory.class)
```

as per the error message and the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html)

Comment: Their tutorial is saying differently: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncjk.html

Comment: Looks like a documentation faux-pas :)